# Can Outlook be configured to Check Names against the GAL and Contacts simutaneously rather than in order of precedence?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2016

Can Outlook be configured to search both the GAL and Contacts when returning Check Names results?

I'm aware that the order of precedence can be specified under Address Book >> Tools >> Options. I'm also aware of the option to ask end users to add contacts needed from the GAL to their local contacts, which is my current solution.

Comment: After testing, I'm afraid there is no built-in option to let Outlook search GAL and Contacts folder at the same time. It always follows the order from Tools > Options in Address Book.   It stops checking when it finds a match.  If you have the GAL listed first and a name starting with the string you've typed is in the GAL, Check Names will find it and stop.  If it doesn't find a name starting with that string and you have your Contacts folder listed after the GAL in the Address Book options, then Check Names will find it in your Contacts.

Comment: Thank you @Perry, that is what I am seeing in my research as well. MS O365 support could not offer an alternative solution either. I understand the purpose, but in 2019 I have users that want options! :)

Comment: maybe we can submit a feedback to Outlook uservoice forum: https://outlook.uservoice.com/